# move object within given perimeter only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a game(not exactly) for kids. It's to illustrate we can make infinite triangles with fixed length of thread, pin board and three pins. Like below:[image]

Students can move any pin. Doing so will create new triangle but the perimeter of the triangle should be of given length. I used the following code:

```
var xMax:Number = drawBoard.x + drawBoard.width;
var xMin:Number = drawBoard.x;
var yMax:Number = drawBoard.y + drawBoard.height;
var yMin:Number = drawBoard.y;

var isDragging1:Boolean = false;
var isDragging2:Boolean = false;
var isDragging3:Boolean = false;

drawBoard.x = xMin;
drawBoard.y = yMin;
var lines:Shape = new Shape();
addChild(lines);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseUpdate);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
pin1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging1);
pin2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging2);
pin3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging3);
function mouseUpdate(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (isDragging1)
    {
        pin1.x = validX(evt.stageX);
        pin1.y = validY(evt.stageY);
        lines.graphics.clear();
        drawLines();
    }
    if (isDragging2)
    {
        pin2.x = validX(evt.stageX);
        pin2.y = validY(evt.stageY);
        lines.graphics.clear();
        drawLines();
    }
    if (isDragging3)
    {
        pin3.x = validX(evt.stageX);
        pin3.y = validY(evt.stageY);
        lines.graphics.clear();
        drawLines();
    }
    evt.updateAfterEvent();
}
function validX(thisX:Number):Number
{
    if (thisX < xMin)
    {
        return (xMin);
    }
    if (thisX > (xMax))
    {
        return (xMax);
    }
    return (thisX);
}
function validY(thisY:Number):Number
{
    if (thisY < yMin)
    {
         return (yMin);
    }
    if (thisY > (yMax))
    {
        return (yMax);
    }
    return thisY;
}
function drawLines():void
{
    lines.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
    lines.graphics.moveTo(pin1.x, pin1.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(pin2.x, pin2.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(pin3.x, pin3.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(pin1.x, pin1.y);
    lines.filters = [new DropShadowFilter()];
}
function startDragging1(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    isDragging1 = true;
}
function startDragging2(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    isDragging2 = true;
}

function startDragging3(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    isDragging3 = true;
}
function stopDragging(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    isDragging1 = false;
    isDragging2 = false;
    isDragging3 = false;
}
function DistanceTwoPoints(x1:Number, x2:Number,  y1:Number, y2:Number):Number
{
    var dx:Number = x1 - x2;
    var dy:Number = y1 - y2;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

It does the half part. I can move any pin and it will create triangle. But the perimeter is different everytime. I tried to restrict it by calculating the distance between three sides. The problem with that is, I can move pin anywhere which makes it difficult to get exact perimeter. As a result, it makes it difficult to move pins smoothly. So, my question is, is it possible to move the pins only to valid location instead of moving along mouse? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can't do that precisely, because Flash has internal position defined by "twips" aka 1/20 of a pixel, and thus shifting a peg one twip to the side will always produce a different perimeter. You can, however, relax the equality condition by specifying a margin of 1 (or 0.5, or whatever but not less than 0.1) from the initial perimeter, and should the resultant perimeter exceed that margin, shorten it by calculating the proper position for the peg just moved, using any algorithm to select the destination.

Comment: @Vesper I believe 1/20 of a pixel is enough precision to go by. I will try to compose a script later if this will be still unanswered by then.

Comment: As an idea, you can use the middle of the non-moving side as the second point of the line where you seek to place the third point being moved, the other line will be the ellipse with two static pegs as center.

Comment: @Vesper I don't need to be that precise. I was thinking of rounding any decimal number while placing or moving any of three pins. Can you elaborate on using middle of non-moving side as the second point?

Comment: Yup. You have your current mouse coords while the peg is being dragged, and two other pegs stand still. Select the average of positiong of two unmoving pegs, and current mouse position, this will be your line on which the third peg will be. Then, use bisection to find a position that's the closest to match your perimeter, then position that peg there (while still dragging). As a result, if your students will move mouse in a big circle, the peg will move in an elliptic trajectory.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'll check it out.